# JSON-LD Schema NUXT

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, json-ld

I am creating a Nuxt application powered by Wordpress.

I am receiving JSON-LD in my WP REST API via a schema plugin.Like so,

```
{
  wp_post_schema: "{"@context":"https://schema.org"}"
}
```

Below is how I use it in NUXT

```
head(){
    return {
        title: 'This is my page title',
        meta: [
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'This is my description' }
        ],
        script: [
            {
                json: this.POST.wp_post_schema
                type: 'application/ld+json'
            }
        ],
    }
},
async asyncData({ $axios, req, params, query, error, route }) {
    var POST;
    try {
      let response = await $axios.get( "https://www.example.com/api);
      return {
        POST: response.data[0].post_meta_fields
      };
    } 
  }
```

My problem is that the JSON-LD rendered on the page is sanitized and is not recognised by google markup tool.
Any suggestion on how i can effectively implement schema markup?

Comment: Are you sure your "response.data[0].post_meta_fields" data  returns a JS object from API and not a string?  else, you have to use "JSON.parse(...)" to init your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [v-html](https://nexladder.com/vuejs-tutorial/vuejs-v-html-directive) to show the content more sanitize.

```
<template>
  <script v-html="POST", type="application/ld+json">
</template>
```